# Why can't ruby open a TCPSocket on my Fedora 20 box?

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, fedora

I'm on Fedora 20 and use ruby 2.1.0. I've the following code from [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html).

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 2000

while line = s.gets # Read lines from socket
  puts line         # and print them
end

s.close             # close socket when done
```

Ruby throws the following error:

```
client.rb:3:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 2000     (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from client.rb:3:in `new'
    from client.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

What could be the reason for this failure? I mean, the code should definitively work, it's dead simple and from a recognized tutorial web page for ruby. I guess that the problem is my operating system, but how do I get it working properly?

Comment: Yes, because there are no TCP service is avaiable on the 2000 local port. Try for example, 80 if any. you can test weither the port is available to connect with: `telnet localhost <port>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sockets are the endpoints of a bidirectional communications channel. Sockets may communicate within a process, between processes on the same machine, or between processes on different continents.

**A Simple Client:**

```
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 2000

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

while line = s.gets   # Read lines from the socket
  puts line.chop      # And print with platform line terminator
end
s.close
```

Now call `TCPServer.open` `hostname`, `port` function to specify a port for your service and create a TCPServer object.

**A Simple Server:**

```
require 'socket'               # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(2000)  # Socket to listen on port 2000
loop {                         # Servers run forever
  client = server.accept       # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts(Time.now.ctime)  # Send the time to the client
  client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
  client.close                 # Disconnect from the client
}
```

read [doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm)

Comment: ok thanks, the problem was that there was no TCPServer available. I'm sorry for that dumb question :/